# Run a pop-up one time per user via cookie

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to be able to run [this](http://pastebin.com/zdc0iPFH) one time per user via a cookie. I have the pop-up set on a [timer](http://pastebin.com/FgzAdn0x) on page load. I don't want to serve the same pop up ever time the page loads up.

Comment: that's where a cookie is a reasonable choice for a solution - though there's no guarantee that everyone will have cookies enabled

Comment: Is there another way to get the same effect without the use of a cookie?

Comment: yes, but if someone doesn't have cookies enabled, then they're very likely not going to have localStorage available - my point wasn't about alternative to cookies